# How can I implement a secure download page/area on a website which requires a digital signature?

Tags: database, security, filesystems, sign

For quality management purposes, the company I work for would like a system which requires a client to read through a disclaimer and then provide an [electronic signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_signature), acknowledging said disclaimer, before being granted access to a download area. After the disclaimer has been signed for, we would also like a feedback system in the form of an automated email, which is sent back to a designated address. I am clueless in this department so I am wondering what is the best way to implement this - most likely best left to a professional but any response here would be great!

I had imagined the process to be as follows:-

1. Company sends a client a pin number and project reference number which is unique to a particular download area (each project we work on and intend to submit to a client would in theory have it's own download area)
2. Client visits a page on our website where they enter the pin number we provide them with, which takes them to their specific disclaimer (disclaimer is different for every project)
3. Client reads disclaimer, signs an electronic signature by providing name, job title and probably some other information yet to be decided.
4. Client is granted access to the download area specific to that project and is able to download the files within.
5. Once the digital signature is signed, an automated email is sent to a designated address to provide us confirmation and evidence of the client's access.

A few further notes:-

- A web-based system would be ideal so it can be integrated into our website - we set up the project on a webpage, entering the specific disclaimer details and uploading the relevant files.
- If the client wishes to gain access to the file area again, they just have to re-enter the reference number and pin number which then bypasses the disclaimer form. However, We must have the option to force the client to re-sign if for example we update some files within the download area.
- To avoid the risk of duplicate pins being issued owing to human error or whatever, some level of automation which provides a randomly generated pin would be great too. We could use a random number generator every time but it would help if the process was streamlined.

I have come across the following - https://www.universign.eu/en/timestamp/ - which seems to be what I'm after but again, the implementation into a website is beyond me.

**My own disclaimer:** Apologies if this is on the wrong site, my ignorance in this area doesn't help so if incorrect, I would appreciate a migration to the relevant sub-site, also unsure on correct/appropriate tags. I can't imagine that I'm the first person to ask for something along these lines so if there is an existing service which I could be directed to, that would be appreciated also!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid this is too broad for Stack Overflow, and any site on the SE network really. The place is really focused on narrow, technical questions. I would talk to a professional

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will do!

Comment: I second the advice to get a security professional consultant, who will design the scheme for you (and maybe implement one).